# How to set "ConnectAs" user in IIS using Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis, permissions

I'm having trouble scripting the "ConnectAs" domain user account for nested web apps in IIS.  My target environment is MS Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8, however, I see the same issues on Windows 7 with IIS 7.5.

For example, suppose I have the "Default Web Site".  Under that I have "MainApplication".  Under that I have another web application for "SubApplication".

I've tried suggestions found on other sites similar to below with partial success: 
These first 2 statements work.

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Default Web Site']/application[@path='/MainApplication']/virtualDirectory[@path='/']" -name "username" -value "mydomain\user" 
Set-WebConfigurationProperty "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Default Web Site']/application[@path='/MainApplication']/virtualDirectory[@path='/']" -name "password" -value "mypassword"
```

I can't seem to get the syntax right for the next two statements:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Default Web Site']/application[@path='/MainApplication/SubApplication']/virtualDirectory[@path='/']" -name "username" -value "mydomain\user" 
Set-WebConfigurationProperty "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Default Web Site']/application[@path='/MainApplication/SubApplication']/virtualDirectory[@path='/']" -name "password" -value "mypassword"
```

In a perfect world, I would be able to do something similar to below to quickly make all of the web applications run under the same domain user account:

```
Get-WebApplication | ForEach-Object { $_ | Set-ItemProperty -Name "username" -Value "domain\user" }
Get-WebApplication | ForEach-Object { $_ | Set-ItemProperty -Name "password" -Value "passwordValue" }
```

or something like this:

```
Get-WebApplication | ForEach-Object { $_.ChildElements | Select-Object -First 1 | Get-Member -Name "Attributes" | Set-Member -Name "userName" -Value "domain\username" }
```

Is there a good way to script set all sites, apps, etc to run under a domain user account?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution I ended up using was to utilize a xpaths to get the full path for each site, app, & virtual directory.  I found that each type needed to be iterated independently.  Below is the function I ended up creating to resolve the issue.

```
function Set-IIS-ConnectAsUser($username, $password)
{
    $dir = Get-Location

    cd IIS:\Sites

    # update all the web sites to run under the context of the specified user
    $webSites = Get-Website
    ForEach($webSite in $webSites)
    {
        $siteName = ($webSite | Select -Property "Name").name
        $fullPath = "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='$siteName']/application[@path='/']/virtualDirectory[@path='/']"
        Set-WebConfigurationProperty $fullPath -Name "username" -Value $username
        Set-WebConfigurationProperty $fullPath -Name "password" -Value $password
    }

    # update all the web applications to run under the context of the specified user
    $apps = Get-WebApplication
    ForEach($app in $apps)
    {
        $xpath = ($app | Select -Property "ItemXPath").ItemXPath
        $fullPath = "$xpath/virtualDirectory[@path='/']" 
        $fullPath = $fullPath.Substring(1)
        Set-WebConfigurationProperty $fullPath -Name "username" -Value $username
        Set-WebConfigurationProperty $fullPath -Name "password" -Value $password
    }

    # update all the virtual directories to run under the context of the specified user
    $virtualDirs = Get-WebVirtualDirectory
    ForEach($vdir in $virtualDirs)
    {
        $xpath = ($vdir | Select -Property "ItemXPath").ItemXPath
        $fullPath = $xpath.Substring(1)
        Set-WebConfigurationProperty $fullPath -Name "username" -Value $username
        Set-WebConfigurationProperty $fullPath -Name "password" -Value $password
    }


    cd $dir
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir ! If only I had a penny for every time I changed password, I would give it all to you and you would be a millionaire by now. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Change parent and child names with yours.

```
Set-WebConfiguration "/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Default Web Site']/application[@path='/parent/child']/virtualdirectory[@path='/']" -Value @{userName='andy';password='password'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below script

```
$deepestPath        =   "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"
$sectionPath        =   "system.applicationHost/sites/site/application/virtualDirectory"
$appPhysicalPath    =   "D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\yourApp"
$userName           =   "domain\serviceaccount"
$password           =   "#######"
$fullPath=$sectionPath+"[@physicalPath='$appPhysicalPath']"
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath $deepestPath -Filter $fullPath -Name "userName" -Value $userName
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath $deepestPath -Filter $fullPath -Name "password" -Value $password
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).